# How to keep track of User ID when email, username, and password can all be changed?

Tags: authentication

In any online account, there is always some basic information associated with the account, that is used to ID a user. In my platform, I am hoping to have the username and email address able to be changed by the user, as well as the password ofc. The question is, how does the system know an account is the same account even when username, email, and password, birthdate, and the like can all be changed?

I have attempted to use the user activity to match users, however, this becomes problematic due to user privacy concerns. I am now wondering if I have to have an identifying feature that cannot be changed by either users of admin/sysops.